# Vue route outside router view returns empty data

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am struggling with getting Vue route outside the `<router-view>` component. Inside, it works fine.

The situation is strange, because the results are like this:

```
mounted : function()
{
    console.log(this.$router);
},
```

It shows this:

```
currentRoute: Object
fullPath: "/activity-calendar"
hash: ""
matched: [{…}]
meta: {__ob__: Observer}
name: "Activity calendar"
params: {}
path: "/activity-calendar"
query: {}
```

This is correct. However, when I try to access this object by

```
console.log(this.$router.currentRoute);
```

I get:

```
fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {}
name: null
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}
```

How come, the objects are different?

Comment: Honestly, that looks mostly like late evaluation. Objects that are logged in the console are evaluated when you open them. E.g. when you have already navigated to that route. You can also use `this.$route` by the way to get the current route. Try putting a `debugger` statement after your console.log to pause execution and evaluate your router then.

Comment: @Sumurai8, that looks like that is the case. Does that mean, the object is filled only after <router-view> is rendered? So, no chance to use router meta data outside <router-view> ? I think, I need to use viex to store the current route.

Comment: There are tons of ways to interact with routes outside the component that is rendered through the route. You can use global navigation guards for example (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow) or put a watcher on `this.$route`. Things like a `:key="$route.fullPath"` allow you to rerender a router-view on a route change, which is useful for animations. Without specifics of what you want to accomplish, I can't really recommend one over the other though.